# How do I verify that current FirebaseUser exists?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

How do I verify that `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` still exists in Firebase Authentication (server-side)?

I deleted the user in my Firebase Console, but `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` still return a user.

So, how do I check that `(await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).uid` is still in my Auth list in the Firebase Console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`reload` method of `FirebaseUser`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/reload.html).

```dart
final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
await firebaseUser.reload();

// This should print `true` if the user is deleted in the Firebase Console.
print(await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() == null);
```

If your user is deleted in the Firebase Console (or disabled) and you call `reload` on the user in Flutter, the next time you call `currentUser`, it should return null, i.e. there is no user authenticated on this device.

Answer (score 0):

using angular,

```
isLoggedIn() {
   return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(first())
}

doSomething() {
  isLoggedIn().pipe(
    tap(user => {
      if (user) {
        // do something
      } else {
        // do something else
      }
    })
  )
  .subscribe()
}
```